# Does id_rsa.pub changes if i will install a older version of ubuntu on my machine

Tags: ssh, 16.10, openssh

Does id_rsa.pub changes if i will install a lesser version of ubuntu on my machine, I want to keep the same id_rsa.pub, as it's registered on my host server.

Comment: There's several "Public Keys" are you referring to those in your `/home/$USER/.ssh` folder or the one for the SSH server?

Comment: Yes Thomas i am referring the same,in my user /.ssh folder, can i take a backup of this file and use it after renistallation, will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To clarify, you are referring to the keys inside the `.ssh` directory in your home directory.

Installing a system won't touch those keys.  Provided you keep the contents of your entire home directory, your SSH public and private keys in `~/.ssh` aren't likely to be replaced by the server.  That said, you should make sure that you keep a backup of these anyways.

Backing up this directory (or its contents) and then putting them back on after a fresh reinstallation will also work - it will use that key and not generate a new one.  (This is why you keep backups of critical data like your SSH keys in a secure place; note that you need both `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, one being the private key and the other being the public key, for key authentication to work with these keys).